# Does $\int1+\sin^2x+\sin^4x+\sin^6x+...\text{dx}=\tan{x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I want to find
$$\int1+\sin^2x+\sin^4x+\sin^6x +...\text{dx}$$
My method was to interpret the integrand as a geometric series with first term $1$ and common ratio $\sin^2x$. Assuming $\sin x\ne1$, I reasoned the integrand should converge.

So the integrand should be equal to
$$\frac{1}{1-\sin^2x}=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}=\sec^2{x}$$
$$\implies \int1+\sin^2x+\sin^4x+\sin^6x +...\text{dx}=\int\sec^2{x}~\text{dx}=\tan x$$
I would just like to know, is this right?
If it is, it seems to me a rather beautiful result.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but there is no need to integrate.

Comment: @YvesDaoust what do you mean? There is no need to integrate to obtain what?

Comment: Integrating adds nothing interesting to the identity.

Comment: @A-levelStudent think of an identity between $\sec^2 x$ and $\tan^2 x$

Comment: @HenryLee $\sec^2x\equiv1+\tan^2x$. So I suppose you mean subtactng 1 from both sides gives $\sin^2x+\sin^4x+...=\tan^2x$. Now what?

Comment: @A-levelStudent you have a similarly nice identity that doesn't require integration

Comment: @HenryLee that doesn't require integration to prove what? I am a bit confused, sorry :) Could you spell it out for me?

Comment: I think the point people are making is that you have the identity $1+\sin^2x +\sin^4x+\sin^6x+\ldots= \sec^2x$, and adding integrals is window dressing.

Comment: @halrankard2 Ah, thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: For any nonnegative $a <1$ the sum $1+a+a^2+ \ldots = \frac{1}{1-a}$. So setting $a=\sin^2x$, we note: $1+\sin^2 x+\sin^4 x + \ldots = \frac{1}{1-\sin^2 x} = \sec^2 x = \frac{d(\tan x)}{dx}$.

Can you finish from here.

ETA: Nevermind just reread you already got this. YES you are correct.

Comment: That is what I did Mike :) Thank you for verifying it though.

Comment: Saw your edit reflected in my answer. Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

The series converges except when $\sin^2x=1$, but in that case $\tan x$ also diverges. All you missed is the $+C$.

Comment: Thanks for the verification :)